# Count co-occurences across groups

Tags: r, dplyr, count, tidyr, contingency

I would like to count co-occurences of a variable across groups. I'm sure there's an easy {dplyr}/{tidyr} solution with `count` or `pivot_` but I'm stuck. Thank you for your help! Below is a reprex of my input and potential output (I don't care about the format of the output, could also be a contingency table). Note that order of the variable does not matter, i.e., "green" then "blue" is the same as "blue" then "green".

```
library(dplyr)

df_in <- tribble(
  ~id, ~color,
  1, "green",
  1, "blue",
  2, "blue",
  2, "green",
  3, "blue",
  3, "red"
)

df_out <- tribble(
  ~colors, ~n,
  "blue-green", 2,
  "blue-red", 1
)
```

Or as a contingency table:
|  | blue |green|red|
| ----- | - | - | - |
| blue  | - | 2 | 1 |
| green | 2 | - | 0 |
| red   | 1 | 0 | - |

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df_in %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 summarise(color = toString(sort(color)), .groups = "drop") %>%
 count(color)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
color           n
<chr>        <dbl>
1 blue, green     2
2 blue, red       1
```

Instead of using `toString` you can use `paste` with `collapse="-"` or `glue::glue_collapse(sort(color), sep = "-")` of course. In addition I added a `sort` if the colors are not similar ordered within the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner in base R:

```
as.data.frame(table(
                 sapply( split(df_in, df_in$id), 
                      function(d) paste( sort(d$color), sep="", collapse="-") ) )
              )
#---------------------------------
        Var1 Freq
1 blue-green    2
2   blue-red    1
```

If you are happy with a contingency table then take off the as.data.frame call:

```
table( sapply( split(df_in, df_in$id), 
             function(d) paste( sort(d$color), sep="", collapse="-")))
#------------------
blue-green   blue-red 
         2          1
```

The problem I see with any of the solutions so far is that there is no "pair creation". Your example may or may not represent the most complex possible inputs. If there are three distinct items in a split based on `id`, then you have not specified how these should be handled.

Comment: Some variants might be: `table(sapply(split(df_in$color, df_in$id), \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="-")))`,  `table(aggregate(color ~ id, df_in, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="-"))$color)` or `table(sapply(by(df_in$color, df_in$id, sort), paste, collapse="-"))`

Comment: @GKi. Agreed. I think that combn and apply on columns might be used if the OP needed pairing for more than two distinct colors per id.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using the `widyr` package:

```r
library(widyr)
df_in %>% 
  pairwise_count(color, id, upper = TRUE) %>%
  # remove pairs with same colours
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pairs = toString(sort(c(item1, item2)))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(pairs))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   item1 item2     n pairs      
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 blue  green     2 blue, green
#> 2 red   blue      1 blue, red
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

`widyr` is a neat little package that provides functions for tidy data which are "mathematically convenient on wide matrices" and then turns the results back into a tidy format. The package is in my experience quite fast and convenient.

Comment: This needs an additional step to remove the extra pairs, although it appears to solve teh issue I identified with the two other solutions in which they didn't actually create pairs from distinct items.

Comment: @IRTFM what are the issues? Please edit your data to show what you mean.

Comment: Ah, I see. I must have missed this in your question.

Comment: @Roman. The example didn’t offer a situation where there were more than two distinct colors within a particular id. So there was no way to tell whether this could occur in the use case and if it could there was no guidance on how it would be handled.

Comment: @IRTFM can you provide some data with distinct colors.

Comment: @Roman I think you mistake me for the OP. I was just a drive-by commenter. There were distinct colors, just not enough of them to satisfy my imagination about what the real data might have been holding. Or maybe there were at most only two. Who know? We were not told the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the adjacency matrix, A, using `table` and `crossprod`, also show it  in long form and then show the graph using the igraph package.

```
A <- crossprod(table(df_in))
diag(A) <- 0

A # as symmetric matrix
##        color
## color   blue green red
##   blue     0     2   1
##   green    2     0   0
##   red      1     0   0

A[upper.tri(A)] <- 0
A  # lower triangular matrix
##        color
## color   blue green red
##   blue     0     0   0
##   green    2     0   0
##   red      1     0   0

A |>
  as.data.frame.table() |>
  subset(Freq > 0) |>
  with(data.frame(pairs = paste(color, color.1, sep = "-"), n = Freq))
##        pairs n
## 1 green-blue 2
## 2   red-blue 1
```

### Plot graph

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A, "undirected")

# combine parallel edges
E(g)$weight <- 1
gg <- simplify(g, edge.attr.comb = list(weight = "sum"))

set.seed(123)
plot(gg, vertex.size = 30, edge.label = E(gg)$weight, 
  vertex.color = adjustcolor(names(V(gg)), 0.5))
```

[image: screenshot]